# Ассоциативный массив php7

Tags: php

Есть вложенный массив и в каждой части этого массива есть значение "speed". Нужно добавить сразу всем елементам с этим значением + 20.То есть если у $porshe 100 должно стать 120 и при этом у $opel тоже должно значение увеличится на 20.

```
$mass = array(
    "porshe" => array(
        "speed" => 100,
        "mark" => "Porshe",
        "year" => 2020
    ),
    "opel" => array(
        "speed" => 150,
        "mark" => "Opel",
        "year" => 1997
    )
);
```

Comment: выложите пример массива. Это важно. Имеет ли вложенные массивы и в каком формате оформлен.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 $cars = array(
    "porshe" => array(
         "speed" => 100,
         "mark" => "Porshe",
         "year" => 2020
     ),
     "opel" => array(
         "speed" => 150,
         "mark" => "Opel",
         "year" => 1997
     )
 );

 foreach ($cars as $key => $value) {
     $cars[$key]["speed"] += 20;
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

```
foreach ($mass as &$car) {
    $car['speed'] +=20;
}
```